# Standard Report Generation Language

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to create a small Python package to generate reports off of spatial data, but instead of trying to recreate the whole formatting language, I am trying to see if there is anything out there that exists.

I need to create PDF reports that can contain:

- Images
- Tables
- different text formats and sizes
- Graphs

Is there a standard report language that covers all of this?

I was taking a look at LaTex, but that seems to cover only 3 of the 4 (not graphing formatting).

Any suggestions would be very welcome.  I'd be open to combining two formatting languages in 1 if there was a clear distinction between say graph and text formatting.

I plan on using matplotlib for the graphing part.  For the text part of the reports, I am considering PyLaTeX, but I'm not 100% sold on any of it.

Thank you.

Comment: probably because your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Start from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/how-to-draw-graphs-in-latex) to see if LaTeX graphs formatting capability fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether there are any out-of-the-box solutions or not. A general solution seems to be kind of complex since there are different people with different tasks (data format, data handling, report layout, report formatting, ...).

However, I have done something similar using the following:

- [`Python`](https://www.python.org/doc/) to handle data
- [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) template engine to [produce a tex-template using Python](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40728/61513)
- [`pdflatex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PdfTeX) to produce the PDF based on the template generated by jinja2
- graphs could be generated using Python only or by a kind of mixed approach

  - using pure Python: Export graphs as images using [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/index.html). [Include them into the tex-file](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) like you would do with 'normal' images.
  - using Latex and Python: Save data to csv-files using Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module or the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) module and generate graphs based on these csv-files using Latex' [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) package. In my opinion this looks much nicer, however the needed time to compile the tex-file increases tremendously
- [`latex-mk`](http://latex-mk.sourceforge.net/latex-mk.html) and [`make`](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/) to do all the needed steps automatically

Answer (score 0):

My [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package for LaTeX might be an option, depending on what your workflow looks like. It allows executable Python code (as well as other languages) within LaTeX documents.

In the `pythontex` approach, you write a valid LaTeX document, rather than using a template engine. So you can easily use standard LaTeX authoring tools like forward/inverse search between the LaTeX source and the PDF output; you're working with LaTeX directly. Python code within the document can be typeset, executed, or both. By default, anything printed by Python goes directly into the LaTeX document and is interpreted as LaTeX, so it's easy to format text using Python and then send it to LaTeX. The `pythontex_gallery` document at GitHub provides an example of what is possible, including plotting.